# Angular5 RequestOptionsArgs search & param what is the difference?

Tags: angular

Learning Angular.... below is a simple practice http.get request

```
let params = new URLSearchParams();
params.set('term', term);
params.set('media', 'music');
params.set('limit', '20');

let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
  this.http.get(this.apiRoot, {params})
      .toPromise()
      .then(
        res => {
            console.log(res.json());
          }
      )
});
return promise;
```

I get this following error:

`Argument of type '{ params: URLSearchParams; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestOptionsArgs'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'params' does not exist in type 'RequestOptionsArgs'.`

If I change `params` to `search` the error goes away but when I check the docs https://angular.io/api/http/RequestOptionsArgs#params  both search and params are URLSearchParams type...

What is the difference between these two attributes?  How to properly use them?  why are there two?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to avoid this error I suggest to do something like that:

```
let params = new URLSearchParams();
params.set('term', term);
params.set('media', 'music');
params.set('limit', '20');

let options = new RequestOptions({params});

let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
  this.http.get(this.apiRoot, options)
      .toPromise()
      .then(
        res => {
            console.log(res.json());
          }
      )
});
return promise;
```

Also looking the Angular's [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/c8a1a14b87e5907458e8e87021e47f9796cb3257/packages/http/src/base_request_options.ts#L88) we can see that `search` and `params` are treated the same and search is deprecated since Angular 4.0.0, so just use `params`. But seeing that you are using Angular 5 I suggest to switch and use the [HttpClient](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient) since the [Http](https://angular.io/api/http/Http) class is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Properly use:

```
let params = new URLSearchParams();
params.set('term', term);
params.set('media', 'music');
params.set('limit', '20');

let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
  this.http.get(this.apiRoot, {search: params})
      .toPromise()
      .then(
        res => {
            console.log(res.json());
          }
      )
});
return promise;
```

Comment: I know using search works... but the question is why... and whats the difference between search and param.